# How can I calcualte a difference between 2 columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, difference

We have a large DataFrame with 30 "Process-Starts" and "Process-Ends". We want to calculate the "Process Time" (Process-End minus Process-Start). Picture [image: img]

Is there a function to calculate all these Process Times and get them in a new DataFrame?

We tried it with this code: Picture [image: img]

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Is there anyone who can help us?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYGsF.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmpiO.jpg)

Comment: `df['Total Time'] = df['End Time'] - df['Start Time']`. It seems your column names are related, so you can write a function to select the appropriate columns, which I'll leave up to you :).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, we need this "function to select the appropriate columns".

Comment: Is your problem resolved?